# How do I stop and restart setInterval() with attributes from its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have this code, where, when I click 'add', it adds a new person to an array. Then when I click 'click' it should change the attributes of that person in the array and use these new attributes (specifically 'interval') in the setInterval() timer, i.e 'person.hours'.

I wish to do it this way as I need to do it individually for each 'Person'.

The main line I need to add code is the following.

```
//restart interval here with new interval
//so re-run personArray[0].hours with the new personArray[0].interval
```

But I'm unsure how to restart the interval with the objects updated attributes.

```js
var personArray = [];

function person(name, age, workhours, interval) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.workhours = workhours;
  this.interval = interval;
  this.hours = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('hello')

  }, interval);
}

person.prototype.update = function() {

  clearInterval(this.hours);
  this.hours = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('newhello');
    //i want to log the persons name here
    console.log(this.name)
    
  }, this.interval);
}

$('#add').click(function() {
  personArray.push(new person('fred', 15, 20, 500))
});


$('#click').click(function() {
  console.log(personArray[0]);
  clearInterval(personArray[0].hours);
  personArray[0].interval = 100;
personArray[0].update();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='add'>
  add
</button>

<button id='click'>
  click me
</button>
```

Here is also a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/reko91/nVyXS/1726/

May make things easier to test out, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not certain what you're trying to achieve but I believe you have to replace the "//restart interval here with new interval"
with something like:

`personArray[0].hours = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('hello')
}, personArray[0].interval);`

*Your code can only affect the first person in the array, but I guess you know that ;)*

Comment: This works perfectly. However, I missed a vital part of my code out, as this is a simplified version of what I am working on. I have managed to solve the problem, but what I asked for originally, you solved, thank you